# matching all highlighted dates in one column to those of another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm currently stuck on this step of my project. [image of my document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha7Nl.jpg) **My ultimate objective is to highlight all highlighted dates in column P in column M.** I was wondering if there was a formula so that I could choose all highlighted values only from column P and highlight the same values in column M.

So I have a bunch of highlighted dates in one column, see column P. I couldn't find a way to copy the highlighted dates to the column M, therefore I had to copy it manually which led to the formation of column N, as I hoped there would be a formula to highlight all same values in column N and column M. I still wasn't able to find the suitable formula to do so.

As there are multiple documents, it would be extremely time consuming to do so all by hand. Thank you in advance, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Formulas don't 'copy' dates from one column to another. Formulas also do not discriminate between values (e.g. Dates) that are 'highlighted' and values that are not 'highlighted'. However, you can use formulas to list all of the dates that exist in both column N and column P. You can also apply the same rules that you used to determine which dates to highlight as the logic between listing a date in column M or not.

Comment: There was a previous function which I did, which was to choose values greater or equal than(in column V not shown in the image), and I used that to highlight the cells in column P. However, as multiple repeats of the date exist in column M, my target column, and they were not on the same row as the dates of column P, I was hoping there would be some way to highlight all of the dates in column M with the same values at the same time with a formula.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Macro solution you could try...

1. We take an intersecting range of used range and Column P in Sheet1
2. The same goes for Column M which returns the same row range.
3. For each cell in Column M use the `MATCH`function to check if the value exists in Column P
4. If a match is found copy the font and background color of the matching cell in Column P and apply the same on to the 'search for' cell in Column M

   ```
   Sub LookupHiglight()
   '
   ' LookupHiglight Macro
   '

   '
       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Dim rngP, rngM, matchCellP As Range
       Dim cellM As Range
       Dim rowIndex_P As Variant

       Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

       Set rngP = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range("P:P"))
       Set rngM = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range("M:M"))

       If rngP Is Nothing Then
           MsgBox "No intersection found with the target column - P:P. Exiting"
           Exit Sub
       End If

       For Each cellM In rngM

           On Local Error Resume Next

           rowIndex_P = Application.Match(cellM, rngP, 0)

           If Not IsError(rowIndex_P) Then

               Set matchCellP = Range("P" & rowIndex_P)
               cellM.Font.color = matchCellP.Font.color
               cellM.Interior.color = matchCellP.Interior.color

           End If

       Next

       MsgBox "Done"

   End Sub
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it's working +1 ☺

Answer (score 1):

What is the condition of highlighted dates in column P or how do you choose which dates do you highlight there? If that is conditional formatting - then you can apply the same conditional formatting to column M. 
If it's a manual selection - you need to go with VBA code, which would do something like 
1. Loop through column P
2. Create an array of highlighted dates
3. Loop through column M and check each cell if that matches a created array. If yes - highlight the cell

See the example of code

```
Sub Sub1()
Dim RngToCheck As Range, rngToUpdate As Range, Cell As Range
Dim CheckColor As Single
Dim MyDates() As Date
Dim Counter As Integer

CheckColor = RGB(198, 239, 206)  '' edit the color as required - it should be the color of highlihgted cells as Red, Green, Blue from format

Set RngToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("P8:P24")  ''' make sure the address of range to check is correct
Set rngToUpdate = ActiveSheet.Range("M8:M24") ''' make sure the address of range to update is correct

''' this loop goes through cells P and create an array of highilted dates
For Each Cell In RngToCheck.Cells
    If Cell.Interior.Color = CheckColor Then
        Counter = Counter + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyDates(1 To Counter)
        MyDates(Counter) = Cell.Value
    End If
Next Cell

''' this loop goes through cells in column M and highiltes same dates as highlighted in column P
For Each Cell In rngToUpdate.Cells
    For Counter = LBound(MyDates) To UBound(MyDates)
        If Cell.Value = MyDates(Counter) Then Cell.Interior.Color = CheckColor
    Next Counter
Next Cell


End Sub
```